# Descargar tabla HTML a excel desde evento de un botón

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Quiero hacer una exportación de una tabla html a excel. Sé que para hacerlo normalmente se utiliza esto:

```
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=NombreArchivo;
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
```

Pero lo que hace esto es que cuando entro a la tabla descarga inmediatamente el excel pero...¿Cómo puedo hacer para descargar el archivo al presionar un botón?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que debieras usar `DataTable`, a mi parecer me a resultado bastante cómodo, y no solo descargas la tabla a excel, sino que también puedes descargarla como *pdf* hacerle un *print* y hasta visualizar las columnas que tu estimes convenientes.

A continuación dejo el enlace de [Datatable](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/simple.html).

Para indicarte un poco como haces uso de estos, debes importar los scripts correspondientes en tu `homedash` por defecto, que sería tu página principal donde visualizas las tablas ahi debes agregar los scripts.

## Scripts

```
<script>//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js</script>
<script>https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js</script>
<script>https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js</script>
<script>//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/buttons.flash.min.js</script>
<script>//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js</script>
<script>//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/pdfmake.min.js</script>
<script>//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/vfs_fonts.js</script>
<script>//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/buttons.html5.min.js</script>
<script>//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/buttons.print.min.js</script>
```

## CSS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
```

## Funcion(puedes hacer un llamado o ponerla en un `script`)

```
$(function() {
    $('#**IDdeTabla**').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

De esa manera puedes implementar `datatable` para la descargar desde un botón tu tabla en excel, importarla a *pdf* o solo copiarla.

Saludos, espero puedas implementar `Datatable` en tu código.

Answer (score 1):

Como lo he manejado yo es de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name='excel'; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= nombre.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);

?>
```

Comment: <?php
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name='excel'; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= nombre.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);

?>

Answer (score 0):

Hola has intentado meterlo dentro de un :

```
    if (isset($_POST['boton-name'])){
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=NombreArchivo;
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
}
```

o te recomiendo que le eches un ojo a PHPExcel https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel