# Tabla html a Excel con formato

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

Tengo una tabla html a la que le aplico Datatables de JQuery, ví que desde el mismo plugin puedo exportar a Excel y la verdad me gustó mucho el formato que le da a las tablas, resulta que de esa tabla ya no necesito mostrarla, sino exportarla directamente a Excel a través de un botón. Hay alguna forma de vincular mi botón al botón de exportar a Exel de Datatables? Hay alguna forma de exportar una tabla Html con formato parecido a ese sin necesidad de usar otro plugin? Gracias!

Comment: Te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas el funcionamiento básico del sitio y también revisar [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y tenga buenas respuestas. Saludos.

Comment: me parece que la pregunta es concreta. Que pena que no pueda responderla por estar "en espera".

Comment: @Erik agrega al menos tu codigo del datatable que tienes a ver si habilitan la respuesta

Comment: Hay una pregunta relacionada con respuesta que podría valer para esta en [Descargar tabla HTML a excel desde evento de un boton](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96624/descargar-tabla-html-a-excel-desde-evento-de-un-bot%C3%B3n)